# org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry:NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, sessionfactory

Getting this error on jboss start. Creating a web application using resteasy and hibernate(SessionFactory).i want to use sessionFactory , Configuration and ServiceRegistry to build session but not able to do that.Please help.Thanks

HibernateUtil

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN""http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mayur_dev</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <mapping class="uk.co.techblue.entity.User" / >
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It's a dependency which is missing at runtime

Comment: This most probably means there is more than one version of this class in the class path. Are you using maven? Take a look at jboss classpath and make it get your classpath libs first. But most probably both your WAR and jboss have this hibernate class.

Comment: Post your POM file.

Comment: @LppEdd can you please, suggest how to add dependency at runtime as i am not able to copy dependency in WEB-INF/lib .

Comment: @MarcCarnéBori yes, i am using maven and i have posted the pom.xml.

Comment: @AmitAnand well, which web application server are you running on? Why you cannot have JARs inside WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: i am using jboss and when i copy dependencies in web-inf/lib ,it shows errors on server start.So sorry if i missed something as i am new in java.